# How can I put a flex item to the end?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the flex items in the center and only the last item at the end, but when I use `margin-left: auto`, the other items are put in the beginning.

```css
#container {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: thistle;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were correct in using `margin-left: auto` on the last flex item. That is one way to position the last item at the end of the main axis. To keep the other flex items positioned in the center, you can simply give the first flex item `.item:first-child` an auto left margin. Now the items 1,2,3,4 are centered in the nav bar with number 5 (the last item) positioned at the end of the row.

```css
#container {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: thistle;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:first-child,
.item:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Yours is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the following result
[image]

the, the following solution would work.

```
.container {
  background-color: wheat;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background-color: thistle;
  border: 0.1rem solid gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 95%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

In the code above, I have used `absolute` positioning for the 5th item, so that it is taken out of the normal flow of the document and we can position it using `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties. Make sure to add `position:relative` to the parent container.

I have centered the 5th item on the center of the container using `transform:translateY(-50%)`. You can decide how far you want to position the 5th element from the left by changing the `left` property.

And the reason `margin-left:auto` does not work, because when you use it, the 5th item takes as much space as possible towards its left and therefore the rest of the 4 items get pushed to the left/beginning of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `margin-left:auto` to the first element, thereby keeping it "fixed" in a sense if you may. You can make a new class for it or simply use `first-child` for it.

```css
#container {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background-color: thistle;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:first-child{
  margin-left:auto;
}

.item:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you!

how about doing like this?

```css
#container {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  background-color: thistle;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}
```

I used position absolute for the element you want to put at the end. And I added position relative attribute to the parent container so that the last element is still within the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

```
It can be achieved by Flex Auto Margin.
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: thistle;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:first-child{
  margin-left: auto;
   
   }

.item:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using a hidden element, you could simply add `margin-left:auto` to the first child and achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks for this it seems to work. I will update the code